# Openshift access to context.xml

Tags: java, openshift

I have deployed a java app on openshift using Eclipse. I did nothing on the command line at all to access the server. Now it seems I have do slight change in my DB-configuration in the server's context.xml file, to prevent the DB from shutting down after one day without use. Someone suggested to add

```
validationQuery="select 1"
```

to the configuration.

Can anyone tell me how to access this file? Is it possible to access it via Eclipse or do I have to us command line tools. I al working from a Mac.

Comment: Your application is going to idle on OpenShift after 24 hours with no HTTP traffic. Upgrade to Bronze/Silver to prevent this behavior. https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, good to know it's a financial and no IT bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is going to idle on OpenShift after 24 hours with no HTTP traffic. Upgrade to Bronze/Silver to prevent this behavior.

https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing

Comment: Added my comment as an answer here to help close this one out :)